# Generating all possible binary matrices such that each row and column adds up to AT MOST 1 for each matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to generate all possible square binary matrices for a given n, such that:
for each binary matrix:

```
1) the rows sum up to at most 1
2) the columns sum up to at most 1
```

Example:
for n = 2, the valid matrices are:

```
[0 0]
[0 0]

[0 0]
[0 1]

[0 0]
[1 0]

[0 1]
[0 0]

[0 1]
[1 0]

[1 0]
[0 0]

[1 0]
[0 1]
```

I need to generate all of these matrices

In python, I have the following brute force way to do it right now for n=k

```
    allwords = list(it.product(*([(0, 1)] * (n**2)))) # Generate all possible binary matrices
    allarrays = map(np.asarray, allwords)  # Convert to array # Convert them toarray
    allmatrices = [a.reshape(n, self.n) for a in allarrays]  # Matrixify # Make a matrix
# The following checks if the matrix has row sum at most 1 and column sum at most 1
    validActions = [x for x in allmatrices if contains(x)]  # Final list has only vlaid matrices
```

contains is defined as

```
def contains(x): # Checks if row and column sums are at most 1 for each entry
        colSums = np.sum(x, axis=0)
        rowSums = np.sum(x, axis=1)
        return (np.all(colSums <= 1) and np.all(rowSums <= 1)) and np.all(x >= 0)
```

This pretty much breaks for n=5 or higher, so I need a smarter way to do this.

The goal is to ultimately create a discrete state space for reinforcement learning, and map each entry in that discrete state space to a valid binary matrix. Valid binary matrices are those that have rows and columns each summing to at most 1.

Comment: Be aware that the number grows exponentially with n: see https://oeis.org/A002720 for a listing of how many matrices there are for each n.

Comment: Yep, absolutely. I mostly just need it to work for n=5/6 I think. I just want to make sure there isn't a way to do this such that I am not generating all the possible and then cutting it down. I think that's what is making this slow right now

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that generates all such matrices using `O(n^2)` space, based on `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def all_bin_mats(n):
  mat_template = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int8)
  # all zeros case
  yield mat_template.copy()
  for k in range(1, n+1):
    for row_subset in combinations(range(n), k):
      row_idx = np.array(list(row_subset))
      for col_subset in combinations(range(n), k):
        col_idx = np.array(list(col_subset))
        for perm in permutations(range(k)):
          mat = mat_template.copy()
          mat[row_idx, col_idx[list(perm)]] = 1
          yield mat

assert sum(1 for _ in all_bin_mats(2)) == 7
assert sum(1 for _ in all_bin_mats(3)) == 34
assert sum(1 for _ in all_bin_mats(8)) == 1441729
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a recursive solution instead. Consider generating all such nxn matrices. Generate the top row first: it either has a 1 in some position, or is all zeroes. For the first case, generate all possible (n-1)x(n-1) matrices, and then for each column position and each smaller matrix generate an nxn matrix by inserting a new row at the top. For example, if you have the submatrix

```
0 1
1 0
```

you can generate the 3x3 matrices

```
1 0 0   0 1 0   0 0 1
0 0 1   0 0 1   0 1 0
0 1 0   1 0 0   1 0 0
```

by inserting a row at the top and a new extra column.

Then, to handle the all-zeros row, simply generate all possible (n-1)xn matrices and add a zero row at the top.

Mathematically this will generate exactly all of the matrices you want.

Comment: Does this address the stipulation of summing to *at most* 1?

Comment: Yes. Each time you insert a new row at the top you also insert a column with only one 1, so you never end up with more than one 1 in any row or column. I also used this recursive strategy to generate the number of matrices of this form and matched it to the OEIS sequence.

Comment: This seems hard to follow. Could you please clarify the algorithm, perhaps by detailing the steps on a small example?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is really just the Rooks problem with a `n x n` board and `m < n` rooks.  Here's a way to solve the problem that, although sub-optimal, I hope you will find interesting.

We first define an alternative way to describe a binary matrix of size `n x n`. We consider the partition of `n` numbers into paths and cycles. A row has a one if it has an incoming edge. The source of the incoming edge indicates the column the one is in. Examples:

```
0->2, 1  
Row 2 has a one in column zero since it has an incoming edge from 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0
---
0->2->0, 1->1
Row 2 has a one in column 0 since it has an incoming edge from 0
Row 0 has a one in column 2 since it has an incoming edge from 2
Row 1 has a one in column 1 since it has an incoming edge from 1
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
---
```

1. Thus, we will first partition `n` numbers into `npart` partitions. (We will need to consider all partitions)

   - example: we partition `0, 1, 2, 3` into 2 partitions: `[0, 1, 2], [3]`.
2. We will allow each partition to either form a cycle or a path (note that paths are non-cyclic). (We will need to consider all combinations of cycles/paths)

   - example: we let `[0, 1, 2]` form a cycle and `[3]` form a path.
3. We permute each partition depending on whether it is a cycle or a path. (we will do this part recursively to consider all arrangements)

   - Example: `[0, 1, 2]` can only form the cycles `0-1-2-0` and `0-2-1-0`. Note that `1-2-0-1` is the same as `0-1-2-0`.
   - Example: if we had chosen `[0, 1, 2]` to form elements of a path, then all permutations of length 3 are valid: i.e. `0-1-2`, `0-2-1`, `1-0-2`, `1-2-0`, `2-0-1`, `2-1-0`.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import more_itertools

def printMatrix(part, iscyc):
    ones = -1*np.ones(n, dtype=int) # ones[2] = 4 means row 2 col 4 is 1, ones[2] = -1 means row 2 is all 0
    for i, p in enumerate(part):
        for j in range(len(p)-1):
            ones[p[j+1]] = p[j]
        if iscyc[i]:
            ones[p[0]] = p[-1]

    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(n):
            print(f"{1 if c == ones[r] else 0} ", end="")
        print("")
    print("")


def permute_part(head, tail, iscyc):
    # head contains permuted partitions
    # tail contains all partitions that haven't been permuted yet
    global count

    if not tail:
        # empty tail means that all partitions have been permuted, and we have arrived at a valid solution
        count += 1
        printMatrix(head, iscyc)
        return

    p = tail[0]
    perms = list(itertools.permutations(p))
    while perms:
        perm = perms.pop()
        if iscyc[len(head)]:
            # only keep distinct cycles in permutations
            cshifts = list(more_itertools.circular_shifts(perm))
            perms = [x for x in perms if x not in cshifts]

        permute_part(head+[list(perm)], tail[1:], iscyc)


def all_part(part, iscyc):
    permute_part([], part, iscyc)

n = 2
count = 0
for part in more_itertools.set_partitions(range(n)):
    npart = len(part)
    for iscyc in itertools.product(range(2), repeat=npart):
        # i-th element in iscyc tells us whether partition i is a cycle
        # now we have a path/cycle partition
        all_part(part, iscyc)
print(f"total: {count}")
```

Output for `n = 2`

```
0 1 
0 0 

0 0 
1 0 

0 1 
1 0 

0 0 
0 0 

0 0 
0 1 

1 0 
0 0 

1 0 
0 1 

total: 7
```

`n=4` gives 32 as does the solution given by [hilberts_drinking_problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60700912/12156872).
`n=8` gives 1441729 as does the solution given by [hilberts_drinking_problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60700912/12156872).

---

## Original answer (incorrect since only considered cases where all rows are 1)

Here's one way to tackle the problem. Firstly, we recognise that any of your desired matrices is in fact a row permutation of the identity matrix. Thus, we only need to generate all possible permutations of n rows, and apply each permutation to the identity matrix. One way to generate the permutations is using Heap's algorithm. The code below is shamelessly taken from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/) with some modifications.

```
import numpy as np

def printArr(a):
    print('------')
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n):
            print(a[i, j],end=" ") 
        print()

def heapPermutation(a, size, n): 

    # if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
    # permutation 
    if (size == 1): 
        printArr(I[a]) # permute the rows of I
        return

    for i in range(size): 
        heapPermutation(a,size-1,n); 

        # if size is odd, swap first and last 
        # element 
        # else If size is even, swap ith and last element 
        if size&1: 
            a[0], a[size-1] = a[size-1],a[0] 
        else: 
            a[i], a[size-1] = a[size-1],a[i] 

n = 3
I = np.identity(n, dtype=int) # use dtype=bool if that is sufficient
a = np.arange(n)
heapPermutation(a, n, n)
```

Result:

```
------
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
------
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 1
------
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
------
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
------
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
------
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

Since I don't know what you want to do with the matrices, I've opted to just print them out and not save them (though saving every one can take a lot of RAM for large n).

Comment: The rows and columns in your example all sum up to 1. OP asked for "at most 1."

Comment: fixed the solution.